# I forget to stop a gui program and run it again. Now I can't close the first program without killing eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a simple GUI app that just draws some graphics on a canvas. The environment is Vista 64. When I run the program, the Windows resize and minimize buttons work, but the close button doesn't. So I have to press the stop button in Eclipse to kill the program.

But sometimes I forget to press stop, and run the program again. The first instance gets stuck and I can't get rid of it without closing Eclipse. If I get careless I can end up with several java windows I can't close. Is there a way to get control of and close the windows? Also, why does the close button not work?

I doubt the code matters in this case but here it is:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class RobotFace extends Canvas{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RobotFace c = new RobotFace();
    c.setBackground(Color.white);
    c.setSize(350, 350);

    Frame f = new Frame();
    f.add(c); 
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 
    f.setSize(350,350);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    int width = 150;
    int height = 200;
    g.drawRect((getWidth()-width)/2, (getHeight()-height)/2, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.gray);
    g.fillRect((getWidth()-width)/2, (getHeight()-height)/2, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.fillRect((getWidth()-80)/2, (getHeight()+50)/2, 80, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    g.fillOval((getWidth()-105)/2, (getHeight()-100)/2, 30, 30);
        g.fillOval((getWidth()+45)/2, (getHeight()-100)/2, 30, 30);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can kill java process, for example with help of process explorer (on Windows)

Comment: *"When I run the program, the Windows resize and minimize buttons work, but the close button doesn't."*  Fix your code rather than stuff about with the development environment.

Comment: Why are you coding AWT in this millennium?

Comment: @Andrew I didn't realize there was a problem with the code, that doesn't help without telling me what's wrong. I'm using AWT because I am following a tutorial that uses it.

Comment: Find a new tutorial.  I recommend [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: *"that doesn't help without telling me what's wrong."*  I suspect it is that the window has no closing functionality, though why that locks Eclipse, I could not say.  I won't tell you how to implement the window closing functionality, since it is different between AWT & Swing, and you should change to Swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Eclipse console for the first application instance should still be available, just not visible. On the Console tab, you can click the toolbar button that looks like a little blue monitor to switch between application instances. To stop the first application instance, you would select that instance using the little blue monitor (it's called "Display Selected Console"), then click the "Stop" button.

Answer (score 3):

[image]You can also kill it using the console of eclips , there is a red button(right cornor) when you open console view in eclips.

To open console view

Window --> Show View --> Console

Answer (score 2):

using this way you can close the Frame/window

```
//add window event adapter
f.addWindowListener(new MyWindowAdapter());


class MyWindowAdapter extends WindowAdapter{

   MyWindowAdapter(){
   }

   //implement windowClosing method
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
      System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to change the behavior of your program so that it actually exits with the window is close (which is **not** the default behavior or Frames in Java.

The [Frame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html) javadoc specifies that it can generate WindowClosing events, which you can use to trigger your app to close (using a class like @Pratik does in their answer).

In my opinion, a better solution would be to replace your frame with a [JFrame](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html) and use it's method [`f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) so that you application with exit when the window is closed. JFrame is written such that it should be a drop in replacement for awt.Frame, but is part of the swing toolkit.